# custom feed og:url for link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i know feed is deprecated but it's the only way i can get the post_id after published without requesting for post_action permission ?

anyway my issue is where the feed takes all the meta og from the link provided instead of the the defined ones in FB UI

```
function shareOnFacebook(link,title,caption,img){

FB.ui(
{
    method: 'feed',
    display: 'popup',
    name: title,
    link: link,
    picture: img,
    caption: 'Ceria8',
    description: caption,
},
    function (response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            alert(response.post_id);
            console.log( response );
        } else {
            alert('Sharing cancelled');
        }
    }
);
```

}

is there anyway for me to prevent FB from getting the meta og from the link provided but from my defined ones via feed method?

[Sharing](https://s31.postimg.org/6uca6q9dn/image.jpg)

[Published](https://s31.postimg.org/4tedzjz97/image.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

made a mistake it should be title instead of name

```
function shareOnFacebook(link,title,caption,img){

FB.ui(
{
    method: 'feed',
    display: 'popup',
    title: title,
    link: link,
    picture: img,
    caption: 'Ceria8',
    description: caption,
},
    function (response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            alert(response.post_id);
            console.log( response );
        } else {
            alert('Sharing cancelled');
        }
);
}
```